# Converging Possibility of Being Chosen by a Skipping and Forgetful Machine

Tags: probability

Suppose that there is a machine that is actually broken: there is a line of people, for the first $r$ people, it will randomly choose one from them with equal possibility and then forget all people before the person it chose, and then choose the next person from the next $r$ people in line.

For example, when $r=2$, for the first choice, it has $\frac{1}{2}$ possibility of choosing #1 or #2 in line. If we are calculating the possibility of the #5 person in line to be chosen, the possibility $P_5$ can be considered as the possibility of choosing $P_3$, skipping #4 and directly reaching #5 or choosing $P_4$, then reaching #5. Therefore,
$$P_5=\dfrac{1}{2}(P_3+P_4).$$

Using the same idea, (by programming) we can see that the possibility $P_i$ of being chosen as $i$ increase converges to a certain value $\frac{2}{3}$.

[Plot of Possibility Converging for $r=2$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoYrQ.png)

Similarly, trying a few other examples with different $r$, we can get that the possibility is slowing converging to $\frac{2}{r+1}$, but why? Is there a theoretical explanation?

Comment: When you say "...for the first *r* people, it will randomly choose one from them with equal possibility..", $Pr = \frac{1}{r}$ for each of the first *r* ?

Comment: I share the confusion of @trueblueanil as to how the algorithm works.  Please, very carefully detail the exact math involved, under the assumption that $~r = 3~$ for example, of the probability that Person #6 will be chosen, and the probability that Person #7 will be chosen.  Personally, I need these examples in order to very carefully scrutinize your posting.

Comment: @true blue anil: The random selection occurs at each step. For example, $P_1=\frac{1}{r}$, but for $r > 1$ we have $P_2=\frac{1}{r}+\frac{1}{r^2}$.

Comment: @user2661923: The main recursion starts at $n=r+1$. The initial values $P_1,...,P_r$ can be computed via a different recursion (or by brute force). For example, using $r=3$, the initial values are
$$
P_1=\frac{1}{3},\;\;\;P_2=\frac{4}{9},\;\;\;P_3=\frac{16}{27}
$$
and then by the main recursion we get
$$
P_4=\frac{37}{81},\;\;\;P_5=\frac{121}{243},\;\;\;P_6=\frac{376}{729},\;\;\;P_7=\frac{1072}{2187}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix a positive integer $r$.

First we show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}P_n$ exists.

Since for $n > r$, we have the linear recursion
$$
P_n=\sum_{k=1}^r \frac{1}{r}P_{n-k}
$$
it follows that $\lim_{n\to\infty}P_n$ exists if and only if all roots of the characteristic equation
$$
x^r=\sum_{k=1}^r \frac{1}{r}x^{r-k}
$$
have absolute value at most $1$.

If instead there is some $x\in\mathbb{C}$ with $|x| > 1$ satisfying the above characteristic equation, then
\begin{align*}
&
x^r=\sum_{k=1}^r \frac{1}{r}x^{r-k}
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
|x^r|=\left|\sum_{k=1}^r \frac{1}{r}x^{r-k}\right|
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
|x|^r\le\sum_{k=1}^r \frac{1}{r}|x|^{r-k}
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
|x|^r\le\sum_{k=1}^r \frac{1}{r}|x|^{r-1}
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
|x|^r\le|x|^{r-1}
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
|x|\le 1
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
contradiction.

Hence $\lim_{n\to\infty}P_n$ exists.

But we can write another recursion for $P_n$ based on the observation that for person $n$ *not* to be selected, the final skip must overshoot person $n$.

It follows that
$$
1-P_n=\sum_{k=1}^{r-1}\frac{r-k}{r}P_{n-k}
$$
hence, letting $L=\lim_{n\to\infty}P_n$, we get
$$
1-L=\sum_{k=1}^{r-1}\frac{r-k}{r}L
$$
which yields $L={\Large{\frac{2}{r+1}}}$.

Comment: I don't really understand this step 
"Since for $n>r$, we have the linear recursion $P_n=\sum^r_{k=1}\frac{1}{r}P_{n−k}$, it follows that $\lim_{n\to \infty}P_n$ exists if and only if all roots of the characteristic equation $x^r=\sum_{k=1}^r\frac{1}{r}x^{r−k}$ has absolute value at most 1", would you mind explaining how did you deduce the roots of characteristic equation from the linear recursion? Thanks!

Comment: @Stephanie Yao: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_recurrence_with_constant_coefficients#Characteristic_polynomial_and_roots